# What to do with a question where answer is "I had a typo"?

Tags: discussion

This may generalize to other questions, but I found a question that seems to me as well formulated, it's an interesting question, but the problem that the questioner user had was a typo in it's configuration.

The question is this: [Zabbix web interface says Zabbix server is offline when failing over to passive node](https://serverfault.com/questions/691822/zabbix-web-interface-says-zabbix-server-is-offline-when-failing-over-to-passive).

In this case, the user simply answered it's own question and accepted it, not having any comments or more answers. There is only 1 vote, and that is on the answer (probably done by the user the made question and the answer).

I had the intention to flag it in order to be closed, but didn't found a valid reason in the flagging options to close the question.

So, what should be done to questions like this, where a user posts a question, but the problem was with the user's configuration? Is this a valid question for ServerFault?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a valid question. Why shouldn't it be? It may even help others who made the same or similar mistakes in the future by encouraging to double check syntax or host names.

Comment: I see: if it's a real problem that the user had, if it shows some degree of investigation on the problem, if the answer itself shows a potential solution for the problem, even if it's just a typo in a configuration file or something similar (which could happen to anyone), then the question is valid.
My main issue was that the question was just a typo and not something more complex, and like so it could not be helpful to others.

Comment: It would be *hugely* helpful to others, if they learned to carefully check their typing before posting.  I've answered questions like that before, too.  My normal approach is to downvote the question (for lack of investigation) and upvote the answer (even if it's by the person who posted the question).